# React rendering is messing up my ref binding with Masonry

Tags: javascript, reactjs, masonry

So I have a `<ul>` list with `<li>` items that I want to masonry in my React app, and those items will later be filtered back and forth.
The problem arises when the component re-renders. I want to do a smooth update with the newly added / removed items from the list.

So here's the code in question so far: (not everything, just the important bits)

```
import Masonry from 'masonry-layout'

componentDidMount: function() {
  this.masonry = new Masonry( this.list, {
    itemSelector: '.card',
    gutter: 10,
    percentPosition: true
  })
},

componentDidUpdate: function() {
  this.masonry.reloadItems()
},

render: function() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{this.props.name}</h3>
      <ul className="card-list" ref={(ul) => { this.list = ul }}>
        {this._renderCards()}
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
},

_renderCards: function() {
  return this.state.cards.map(card => (
    <Card key={card.name} {...card} />
  ))
},
```

What seems to happen is that each time the component updates the `<ul>` is re-rendered and loses its binding with masonry which makes me unable to do anything further with it, which I don't really understand why it does, since only the list is actually updated.

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: Here's the documentation on Masonry's reloadItems() http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#reloaditems

Answer (score 0):

After much searching and digging around, it seems like it was kind-of working as I had intended, the only thing I was missing was that reloadItems() does not trigger any layouting done by Masonry, so calling it after I reloaded the items solved the problem like so:

```
componentDidUpdate: function() {
  this.masonry.reloadItems()
  this.masonry.layout()
},
```